# Change the charset attribute in the html header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers

My whole app is serving stuff in utf-8, only one page (xml) should return a ISO-8859-1 page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Now, how can I change the header attribute in order to have the ISO-8859-1 served.

The result of

```
wget --save-headers http://79.125.52.185/kdb/jobs/jobs_ch
```

is

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
...
Content-Length: 34899
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<JOBS>
  <INSERATE>
    <INSERAT>
      <ORGANISATIONID>10</ORGANISATIONID>
      <INSERATID>1532</INSERATID>
      <VORSPANN>Gemeinsam mit Ihrem Team sorgen Sie f&#252;r Kundenservice
```

where

```
 f&#252;r
```

should be

```
 für
```

and the

```
 Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

should be

```
 Content-Type: application/xml; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**Current Source**

controller

```
def jobs_ch
  @jobs = ...
   render :action => 'jobs_ch', :layout => 'empty'
end
```

view

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0" , :encoding => "ISO-8859-1"
xml.JOBS{
...
```

Comment: do you know about :layout => false, BTW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I feel your pain. I solved the same problem with such an after_filter:

```
after_filter :this_xml_needs_to_be_in_cp1251

def this_xml_needs_to_be_in_cp1251
  response.charset = 'cp1251'
  response.body = Iconv.conv('cp1251//IGNORE//TRANSLIT','UTF-8',response.body)
end
```

I'd edit the snippet to your needs, but I'm not sure about the encoding's Iconv code.

Answer (score 0):

Sicher, dass die Daten nicht bereits URL-Codiert sind?

Möglicherweise bringts was, wenn du

```
CGI.unescape(string)
```

verwendest, für deine Daten?

Comment: ich glaube die Zeichen sind nicht das Problem, das Problem ist, dass im Header Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8 steht.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to change your webservers-encodings?

f.e. adding another charset?

see http://intertwingly.net/blog/2004/09/23/Copy-and-Paste

or maybe this:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/111537